# Relations in resources?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So I'm planning to start using [resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources) for my "API" (vue endpoint). So I started to search for some tutorials about the subject, and found a youtuber that describes the process. And I started making my own API resource. The youtuber shows briefly [how to use the relations](https://youtu.be/Gyr5ZMNaPbc?t=22m15s), but the thing is that I receive `Property [description] does not exist on this collection instance.` when trying to use the relation in the resource.

The current setup is:

```
$stack = Stack::select(['id', 'name', 'subject_id', 'description', 'image'])->where('id', '=', $requestId)->first();
$questions = $stack->load('question.choiceInRandomOrder');

return $questions;
```

And with resource it would be something like (notice `choiceInRandomOrde`, I would need that relation also):

```
return [
   'subject' => $this->subject->name,
   'name' => $this->name,
   'slug' => $this->slug,
   'description' => $this->description,
   'image' => $this->image,
   'questions' => [
       'description' => $this->question->description,
       'is_info' => $this->question->is_info,
       'source' => $this->question->source,
       'image' => $this->question->image,
      ]
   ];
}
```

And for testing, I have setup the following in my routes `web.php`

```
use App\Stack;
use App\Http\Resources\StackResource;

Route::get('/json', function(){
    $stack = Stack::find(2);
    return new StackResource($stack);
});
```

Comment: How big is the project, if its more than X tables (or its going to be complicated) forget resources use fractal (or [spatie/fractalistic](https://github.com/spatie/fractalistic)) instead.

Comment: its four tables, small project =)

Comment: Have you seen official docs on querying relationships with resources? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources#conditional-relationships

Comment: Yes, I linked it in my post

Comment: @Kyslik honest question.. why? IMHO, API Resources are as powerful as Fractal.

Comment: `$questions` is not your questions, `load` returns the model you called `load` on, not the relationship(s) you are loading

Comment: `$questions` contains both `Stack` and the relational questions. I might not have named them after basic coding standard, but the questions is there anyway =) I want to achieve the same, but with a resource. So I don't have to do messy eloquent calls

Comment: @HCK I've done my research 3-4 months ago, not sure if anything changed since then but I stick to the fractal for now. Perhaps serializers changed at will, more robust configuration, includes via GET.

Answer (score 0):

You try to access the `name` of `subject` in `'subject' => $this->subject->name`, but you do not load the relation.

Comment: Thanks! I made an error, it is line `'description' => $this->question->description,`, see me updated question. (`'subject' => $this->subject->name` works as supposed!)

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i'm right but i thnk it has to be with the fact that ure not doing an Eloquent call but a Query Builder call (when doing  `$stack = Stack::select ...` ). Why select just some fields in the call if you can choose the parameters to show directly in the model class? (see [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json)).

Try to doing an Eloquent call instead (something like `Stack::find(1)`) and test it. It should work.

Comment: because why pull information you dont need from the database? ... eloquent uses query builder

Comment: Yes, but when using Eloquent the result is a collection of objects (that also keep the properties of relationships and so on), but if you interact directly with the database it is just and array.

Comment: they are not interacting directly with the database ... eloquent models are builders .. all query builder methods are available for eloquent, it is still eloquent it still returns a model or null from `first/find` etc ...  `DB::table(...)` would be query builder, not eloquent

Comment: but yes that query could be simplified by calling `find($id, $columnsToSelect)`